# Is it possible to do a CQL filtering on an array field in a Postgis DB

Tags: postgis, geoserver, cql-filter, array

I have a Postgis (2.2.3 in PostgreSQL 9.5) database with a view that has aggregate array fields.

I can filter on these fields directly on the DB with

```
Select * from myschema."ViewWithArrays" v
where '7415CM' = ANY(v."Postcodes")
```

But I cannot seem to find the syntax for filtering these array fields with CQL to my Geoserver (2.10.1) which has the view as a layer.
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference

The IN keyword seems logical, but the following does not work:

```
CQL_FILTER=7415CM IN Postcodes
```

This gives the following error:

> Could not parse CQL filter list. Encountered "7415 CM" at line 1,
>   column 25. Was expecting one of: "not" ... "include" ... "exclude" ...
>   "(" ... "[" ... "id" ... "in" ...  ...  ...
>    ... "-" ...  ...  "*" ...
>    "/" ...  "+" ... 
>   "-" ...  "not" ...  "like" ...
>    "ilike" ...  "exists" ...
>    "does-not-exist" ...  "is" ...
>    "between" ...  "=" ...
>    ">" ...  "<" ... 
>   ">=" ...  "<=" ...  "<>" ... Parsing
>   : VerzamelingId = 241 AND 7415CM IN Postcodes.

if you need the stacktrace of the geoserver, let me know, I will add it than

**edit**:

putting the statement 7415CM in single quotes does not help:

> Could not parse CQL filter list. Encountered "\'7415CM\' IN" at line
>   1, column 25. Was expecting one of: "not" ... "include" ... "exclude"
>   ... "(" ... "[" ... "id" ... "in" ...  ...  ...
>    ... "-" ...  ...  ...
>    ...  "*" ...  "/" ...
>    "+" ...  "-" ... 
>   "not" ...  "like" ...  "ilike" ...
>    "exists" ...  "does-not-exist" ...
>    "is" ...  "between" ...
>    "=" ...  ">" ...  "<"
>   ...  ">=" ...  "<=" ...
>    "<>" ... Parsing : VerzamelingId = 241 AND '7415CM'
>   IN Postcodes.

Comment: most probably you have a syntax error. it parses `7415CM` (your where-filter) as a command.

Comment: than, what should the syntax be? and is it even possible to do this with the IN keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the argument "7415 CM" within quotes, put the field name first and wrap the possible values in parentheses

```
Postcodes in ('7415CM')
```

Let's note that the error message added a space between the number and CM, meaning it is interpreting `CM` as a command, not as part of the parameter value.

Comment: sorry to say that I had already tried that, error is in updated question

Comment: @DaniëlTulp see updated answer

Comment: @DaniëlTulp For info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: thanks for the link and the solution seems to work, although now I have the problem that apparently, Geoserver does not like array fields..... (they are not listed when I want to create a layer from the view, I missed that when I did it the first time around), thanks for your answer

Comment: GeoSErver indeed currently has no idea of what an array field is, and what to do with it. Some simple code needs to be written to add such support.

Comment: @AndreaAime what would be the route to take to get such support in GeoServer?

Comment: I normally refer people to this guide: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer
If you want to do changes yourself please hop on the developer list, we'll be happy to give you pointers.

Comment: Alternatively, though performance might suffer, don't aggregate into an array but use `string_agg` and search with `like`